# Linq error - does not contain a property with the name 'COname'

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In the data binding process I get the following error when binding to a field in a formview:

DataBinding: 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[[LinqClassLibrary.dbml.OrderAgency, LinqClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'COname'.

code snippet:

```
<asp:Label ID="COnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderAgencies.COname") %>' />
```

Looking at the object browser it shows:

From my "Order" table:

```
public System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<OrderAgency> OrderAgencies { set; get; }
Member of LinqClassLibrary.dbml.Order
```

and From my "OrderAgency" table:

```
public string COname { set; get; }
Member of LinqClassLibrary.dbml.OrderAgency
```

This used to work. And from my understanding of Linq2Sql this is the correct way to reference the field in the OrderAgency table from the Order table. I'm still fairly new at linq2sql so maybe I've missed something obvious here.

Comment: According to your model an Order can have more than one Agency. Therefore `OrderAgencies` is an EntitySet, and not a single object.

Comment: Klaus is right. The exception explains it all. An `EntitySet<T>` does not contain a property named `COname`. Make sure you have a single `OrderAgency` object, not a collection of them.

Answer (score 2):

The comments on your question have already revealed the answer so here is an *answer* answer (as opposed to a *comment* answer):

`OrderAgencies` is an `EntitySet<>` (*collection* of entities) but in your binding you're trying to access `COName` which is a property of the `OrderAgency` entity class (a *single* entity).  In your binding you'll need to reference a single `OrderAgency` entity to be able to access its `COName` property.

Comment: +1 for calling out the comment answer. I freaking hate those.